# Read Content Of File from iCloud

Tags: ios, swift3, icloud, nsfilemanager

I have successfully got the list of files stored in iCloud drive. When I check the file exists at the path, it returns true.

But when I try to get the content of a file, it's not allowing me to read the file and providing some garbage data.

Can I read the file from iCloud directly or needs to move it to app's documents folder first?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is my code

**iCloud URL**

```
static let iCloudDocumentsURL: URL? = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents")
```

**File Path**

```
let filePath =DocumentsDirectory.iCloudDocumentsURL?.appendingPathComponent(file).path
```

**Checking File exists and its showing "File Available"**

```
if FileManager().fileExists(atPath: filePath)
        {
            print("File Available")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Not Available")
        }
```

Getting data of file and it showing **176** bytes which is actually **76756** bytes

```
let fileData = NSData.init(contentsOfFile: filePath)
```

Comment: That's how you read the content of a file?  A file like a text file?  For which Swift version?  For Swift 3?

Comment: Using Swif3. There is no issue with reading a file. If I read file from documents directory, its works fine.

Comment: @GirishM did you resolve this?

Answer (score -2):

This objective C code may help you to read files from iCloud...

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.content"] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];    //public.composite-content
documentPicker.delegate = self;
[documentPicker setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[self presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Implement `UIDocumentPickerDelegate` Methods

```
- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url {

    NSLOG(@"controller.documentPickerMode = %d", controller.documentPickerMode);

    if (controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerModeImport) {
        //here you can download your file and store in document dir.
        //in "url" you get url of the file to be downloaded
       //so you can check here whether file is already available or not
    }
}

- (void)documentPickerWasCancelled:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller {

    NSLOG(@"documentPickerWasCancelled");
}
```

Comment: I don't want to show document picker. I have already worked on document picker. In my project, I need to give the option to pick file from documents folder or iCloud with custom UI.